# How to change the modal content when you press different buttons

Tags: javascript, html

How to change the modal content if I click different buttons. Because I tried to figure it out but it didn't work. It showed the modal content 1 in all buttons.

```
<div class="showmodal">
        <button class="show-modal">Show modal 1</button>
        <button class="show-modal">Show modal 2</button>
        <button class="show-modal">Show modal 3</button>
     </div>

      <div class="modal hidden">
        <button class="close-modal">X</button>
         <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
          tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
          veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
          commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
          velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
          occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
          mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal hidden">
      <button class="close-modal">X</button>
       <p>
        jjjjjqui officia deserunt
        mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal hidden">
      <button class="close-modal">X</button>
       <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       in culpa qui officia deserunt
        mollit anim id est laborum.ff
      </p>
  </div>
      <div class="overlay hidden"></div>

</div>
```

This is the whole code:

https://codepen.io/jujuju12/pen/XWMzPBe

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's the way you want it, but I've modified the code.

1. i used event delegation. Instead of adding an event to each button, the event is detected in the parent node.
2. i have modified some HTML and javascript code.

---

```html
<html>
<body>
       <h2>How To Play This Game</h2>

      <div class="showmodal">
        <button class="show-modal" data-id="0">Show modal 1</button>
        <button class="show-modal" data-id="1">Show modal 2</button>
        <button class="show-modal" data-id="2">Show modal 3</button>
     </div>

      <div class="modal hidden">
        <button class="close-modal">X</button>
         <p class="modal-content">
         content 1
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="overlay hidden"></div>

  <script src="game.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
'use strict';
const modalData = ['content1', 'content2', 'content3'];
const $modalContainer = document.querySelector('.showmodal');

const $modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
const $content = document.querySelector('.modal-content');
const $overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');
const $btnCloseModal = document.querySelector('.close-modal');

console.log($btnCloseModal);

$modalContainer.addEventListener('click', e => {
  
  const { id } = e.target.dataset;
  
  $content.innerText = modalData[id];
  $modal.classList.remove('hidden');
  $overlay.classList.remove('hidden');
});

$btnCloseModal.addEventListener('click', () => {
  
  $modal.classList.add('hidden');
  $overlay.classList.add('hidden');
});
```

I hope this was the answer you were looking for. Thank you.